# Create bazel rule for grpc-web

Tags: bazel, bazel-rules, grpc-web

The command that the official grpc-web dependency specifies to generate the protobuf JS code is:

protoc -I . -I=$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.16.0/third_party/googleapis --js_out=import_style=closure,binary:. --grpc-web_out=import_style=closure,mode=grpcweb:. path/to/service.proto

See https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web?tab=readme-ov-file#client-configuration-options.

However, I am trying to accomplish this by encapsulating the logic in a Bazel rule. It seems I should be using ctx.actions.run() to run the protoc executable. However, I'm not familiar with Bazel and am not sure how to get a working bazel rule that successfully generates protobuf code to my bazel-bin/. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
#    ctx.actions.run(
#        inputs = ctx.files.srcs,
#        outputs = [ctx.outputs.out],
#        executable = "//tools/protobuf:protoc",
#        arguments = [
#            "-I.",
#            "-I=$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/grpc-gateway@v1.16.0/third_party/googleapis",
#            "--js_out=import_style=closure,binary:" + protoc_output.path,
#            "--grpc-web_out=import_style=closure,mode=grpcweb:" + protoc_output.path,
#        ] + [src.path for src in ctx.files.srcs],
#        progress_message = "Generating protobuf JS Closure code for gRPC-Web",
#    )
#
##    ctx.actions.write(
##        output = protoc_output,
##        content = "Generated protoc output for " + ctx.label.name,
##    )
```

I would expect this to generate the files and place them in bazel-bin/ for me to reference later. However, I'm not seeing any files generated